# How are widgets rendered in DOJO

Tags: dojo, tabcontainer, dijit.layout

How are widgets rendered in Dojo? What is the flow or sequence with which various JSs are called. I am trying to understand how the internal code is contructed for widget.
For example: If TabContainer is used , we can see the following code:

```
<div dojoattachpoint="containerNode"
     class="dijitTabPaneWrapper
     dijitTabContainerTop-container dijitAlignClient"
     aria-labelledby="tabContainer_tablist_dijit_layout_ContentPane_0"
     style="left: 0px; top: 28px; position: absolute; width: 748px; height: 335px;">
```

So how is Dojo constructing all these?

Answer (score 1):

Many widgets use html templates. On top of the templates, various functions are triggered during the widget life cycle. There, you can manipulate the dom programmatically.

For information on how this is done, read the following links :

- http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/templated/
- http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/24/creating-dojo-widgets-with-inline-templates/
- https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/understanding_widget/